# Convert a List to a Data Frame with Each Level goes Into a Single Column

Tags: r

I have a list of vectors as in the example

```
l=list(a=c("AA","AAA"),b=c("BB","BBB","BBBB"),c=c("CC"))
```

What I want is to generate a data frame with two columns. One contains the first level and the second contains the second level. for example I need this output

```
df=data.frame(fst=c(rep("a",2),rep("b",3),rep("c",1)),snd=c("AA","AAA","BB","BBB","BBBB","CC"))
```

what I did is, I converted the list into a wide formatted data frame and then melted it using reshape2 package as in the following:

```
library(plyr)
library(reshape2)
df=ldply(l,data.frame)
df_wanted=melt(df2,id.vars=".id",na.rm=TRUE)
```

so this has enabled me to get the needed results (still needs minor processing) but I was wondering if there is an easier solution to directly convert the list to the `df_wanted` format because in my case `df`will result in huge number of columns. 
Thank you so much for your comments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the basic `stack` command

```
setNames(stack(l), c("snd","fst"))

#    snd fst
# 1   AA   a
# 2  AAA   a
# 3   BB   b
# 4  BBB   b
# 5 BBBB   b
# 6   CC   c
```

Comment: Wish I could give +50 to this answer.

Answer (score 3):

You could have used `melt` directly on `l`

```
setNames(melt(l), c("snd", "fst"))
 #   snd fst
#1   AA   a
#2  AAA   a
#3   BB   b
#4  BBB   b
#5 BBBB   b
#6   CC   c
```